# Required props loadingElement or googleMapURL is missing. You need to provide both of them

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, react-google-maps

I have this props but still get the same error. Required props loadingElement or googleMapURL is missing. You need to provide both of them.

```
import React from 'react';
import { GoogleMap,
     withScriptjs, 
     withGoogleMap  } from 'react-google-maps'


function Mapp () {
return (
<GoogleMap 
  defaultZoom = { 10 } 
  defaultCenter = {{ lat: 45.421532, lng: -75.697189 }}
/>
)
}

const WrapperMap = withScriptjs( withGoogleMap(Mapp))



export default function Maps() {

return (
<div style = {{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}>
  <WrapperMap
    googleMapUrl = {`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
    v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,
    drawing,places&key=YOUR_KEY`}
    loadingElement = { <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
    containerElement = { <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
    mapElement = { <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  />
 </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are using the parameter `googleMapUrl` instead of `googleMapURL`. Once you change this, the code will successfully run. I also removed your API key. Please don't share your API key in public sites like StackOverflow in the future.
Here's a [working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-map-stackoverflow-answer-xrqjai?file=src/App.js).